# Load external CSS after compiling .pug to html

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, pug

I have a example.pug and a example.css. On the command line I use `pug example.pug` which generates a `example.html` page. Only problem is, the external styling doesn't link when I open the page in a browser. How do I fix this?

Most questions similar to this involve Express, which I'm not using.

Thanks! I'll add the file directory below. 

`-Directory
 |-Styles
   |-example.css
 |-Examples
   |-examples folder
     |-example.pug`

Hopefully that makes sense. I've also moved the .css directly into the same as my .pug, like so.

`-Directory
|-example.pug
|-example.css`

I then link as `link(href='./tailwater.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')`
 and the css still won't load on the page.

Comment: Probably a path problem. Since you are serving it locally without a server. Add the html generated and the directory tree if possible.

Comment: I'll edit and add the structure in a bit, I'm away from my machine at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to writing incorrect path to css files

Suppose this is your directory structure

```
-Directory
|- example.css
|- example.html(generated file)
|- example.pug
```

Then write link as

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="./example.css")
```

this way your example.html will contain

```
<link rel="style" href="./example.css">
```

If directory is not of given structure, then adjust href accordingly

Comment: This solved my problem. I just moved the .css file to the same directory as my .pug and moved on.